# call function with parameters and return value on button press

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have created a function that sends a request to my nodejs server and takes some parameters (username password etc.) and returns the response status. I would like to have a button activate the function and use text from text boxes to put in the parameters and change the behavior of my app based on the return value of the function. When I do something like this for instance

```js
<Button
  title="send"
  onPress={console.log(sendCreateUser("testabsdf", "test", "test", "password"))}
/>;
```

The function opens the second the page is loaded, not when the button is pressed, and it always prints undefined, even though if instead of returning the response.status I use console.log it will work perfectly. I just want to give the user an error message if I don't get the status 201, and I want to take user input and include it in my fetch-post to my server after a button press

Answer (score 1):

Usually `onPress` function needs to be a callback :

```
onPress={()=>sendCreateUser('testabsdf','test','test','password')}
```